# mix date periods in two dataframe

Tags: r, date, dataframe, as.date

I have a dataframe with clients, the hotel they are staying at and the arrival and departure dates of the hotel.

```
client<-data.frame( id = 1:5, 
                    arrive = c("2019-05-01", "2018-01-03", "2019-04-05", "2015-05-03", "2017-12-02"), 
                    departure = c("2019-05-31", "2018-01-21", "2019-04-25", "2015-05-13", "2017-12-30"),
                    reg_com= c(12654, 12657, 12666, 12589, 12546)) 

client[, 2] <-as.Date(client[, 2])
client[, 3] <-as.Date(client[, 3])

# I don't care about the years
client[, 2]<-format(client[, 2], format="%m-%d")
client[, 3]<-format(client[, 3], format="%m-%d")
```

Also a dataframe with hotels and opening dates. The years of the opening dates do not matter to me because every year the hotel opens the same days. X1O and X1C refers to the first period in which it is open, X2O and X2C refers to the second period in which the hotel is open.
That is, the hotel is open = [X1O, X1C] and [X2O, X2C] and [X3O, X3C].

```
hotel_periodes<- data.frame(reg_com = c(12654, 12657, 12666, 12589, 12546),
                  x1O = c("2018-12-01", "2019-03-04", "2019-04-30", "2018-12-01","2019-04-01"),
                  X1C = c("2019-04-01", "2019-05-04", "2019-12-31", "2019-01-01", "2019-06-01"),
                  X2O = c(NA, "2019-06-30", NA, "2019-02-20", "2019-07-01"),
                  X2C = c(NA, "2019-09-30", NA, "2019-02-30","2019-11-02"),
                  X3O = c(NA, "2019-12-01", NA, "2019-06-20","2019-12-01"),
                  X3C = c(NA, "2019-01-30", NA, "2019-11-01","2019-12-30")
                  )
hotel_periodes[, c(2)]<-as.Date(hotel_periodes[, c(2)])
hotel_periodes[, c(3)]<-as.Date(hotel_periodes[, c(3)])
hotel_periodes[, c(4)]<-as.Date(hotel_periodes[, c(4)])
hotel_periodes[, c(5)]<-as.Date(hotel_periodes[, c(5)])
hotel_periodes[, c(6)]<-as.Date(hotel_periodes[, c(6)])
hotel_periodes[, c(7)]<-as.Date(hotel_periodes[, c(7)])

# I don't care about year
hotel_periodes[, c(2)]<-format(hotel_periodes[, c(2)], format="%m-%d")
hotel_periodes[, c(3)]<-format(hotel_periodes[, c(3)], format="%m-%d")
hotel_periodes[, c(4)]<-format(hotel_periodes[, c(4)], format="%m-%d")
hotel_periodes[, c(5)]<-format(hotel_periodes[, c(5)], format="%m-%d")
hotel_periodes[, c(6)]<-format(hotel_periodes[, c(6)], format="%m-%d")
hotel_periodes[, c(7)]<-format(hotel_periodes[, c(7)], format="%m-%d")
```

I want to know if when the client stayed the hotel was open or closed.

```
result<-data.frame( id = 1:5, 
                    arrive = c("2019-05-01", "2018-01-03", "2019-04-05", "2015-05-03", "2017-12-02"), 
                    departure = c("2019-05-31", "2018-01-21", "2019-04-25", "2015-05-13", "2017-12-30"),
                    reg_com= c(12654, 12657, 12666, 12589, 12546), 
                    OPEN_HOTEL= c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE )
                    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is the following. First I prepare the hotel_periods data in the right format, transforming it from wide to long.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

hotel_periodes <- hotel_periodes %>% 
  gather(period, times, -reg_com) %>% 
  mutate(oc = str_extract(period, "[OC]"), 
         oc = if_else(oc == "O", "open", "close"), 
         period = as.numeric(str_extract(period, "\\d")), 
         times = as.Date(times)) %>% 
  spread(oc, times) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(open)) %>% 
  select(reg_com, period, open, close)

hotel_periodes
#    reg_com period       open      close
# 1    12546      1 2019-04-01 2019-06-01
# 2    12546      2 2019-07-01 2019-11-02
# 3    12546      3 2019-12-01 2019-12-30
# 4    12589      1 2018-12-01 2019-01-01
# 5    12589      2 2019-02-20 2019-02-28
# 6    12589      3 2019-06-20 2019-11-01
# 7    12654      1 2018-12-01 2019-04-01
# 8    12657      1 2019-03-04 2019-05-04
# 9    12657      2 2019-06-30 2019-09-30
# 10   12657      3 2019-12-01 2019-01-30
# 11   12666      1 2019-04-30 2019-12-31
```

Then I merge this data.frame with the clients data. You say the year doesn't matter to you. Nevertheless we need the right year to compare the dates. As you say the opening periods stay constant over the years I do a little trick an set the close year to the departure year and the open year either to the departure year as well or to one year before (to capture dates where the hotel is open from December to January). 
Then I compare the open, close, arrive, and departure dates and return TRUE if arrive and departure lie between open and close. Then finally I summarize the results for each client, hotel and arrive and departure date.

```
client <- client %>% 
  mutate(arrive = as.Date(arrive), 
         departure = as.Date(departure))

left_join(client, hotel_periodes, by = "reg_com") %>% 
  mutate(close = `year<-`(close, year(departure)),
         open = if_else(`year<-`(open, year(departure)) <= close, 
                        `year<-`(open, year(departure)), 
                        `year<-`(open, year(departure) - 1)),
         between = open <= arrive & departure <= close) %>% 
  group_by(id, arrive, departure, reg_com) %>% 
  summarize(OPEN_HOTEL = any(between))

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   id, arrive, departure [5]
#      id arrive     departure  reg_com OPEN_HOTEL
#   <int> <date>     <date>       <dbl> <lgl>  
# 1     1 2019-05-01 2019-05-31   12654 FALSE  
# 2     2 2018-01-03 2018-01-21   12657 TRUE   
# 3     3 2019-04-05 2019-04-25   12666 FALSE  
# 4     4 2015-05-03 2015-05-13   12589 FALSE  
# 5     5 2017-12-02 2017-12-30   12546 TRUE
```

#### Data

Note: I changed the date `2019-02-30` to `2019-02-28` manually, as this is not the main focus of the question. Nevertheless it is necessary to validate the dates before you merge the data.frames.

```
client <- 
  data.frame(id = 1:5, 
             arrive = c("2019-05-01", "2018-01-03", "2019-04-05", "2015-05-03", "2017-12-02"), 
             departure = c("2019-05-31", "2018-01-21", "2019-04-25", "2015-05-13", "2017-12-30"),
             reg_com= c(12654, 12657, 12666, 12589, 12546), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

hotel_periodes <- 
  data.frame(reg_com = c(12654, 12657, 12666, 12589, 12546),
             x1O = c("2018-12-01", "2019-03-04", "2019-04-30", "2018-12-01","2019-04-01"),
             X1C = c("2019-04-01", "2019-05-04", "2019-12-31", "2019-01-01", "2019-06-01"),
             X2O = c(NA, "2019-06-30", NA, "2019-02-20", "2019-07-01"),
             X2C = c(NA, "2019-09-30", NA, "2019-02-28","2019-11-02"),
             X3O = c(NA, "2019-12-01", NA, "2019-06-20","2019-12-01"),
             X3C = c(NA, "2019-01-30", NA, "2019-11-01","2019-12-30"), 
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This finally work for me:

```
y<- merge(client, hotel_periodes, by.x="reg_com", all.x=TRUE)


is.between<-function(x, a, b) {
 for( i in 1:length(a)){
   if(a[i]>b[i]){
    year(a[i])<-2018
  }}
  (x > a) & (b > x) 
  return((x > a) & (b > x) )
} 


y$arrive<- as.Date(y$arrive, '%m-%d')
y$departure<- as.Date(y$departure, '%m-%d')

y$x1O<- as.Date(y$x1O, '%m-%d')

y$X1C<- as.Date(y$X1C, '%m-%d')

y$X2O<- as.Date(y$X2O, '%m-%d')

y$X2C<- as.Date(y$X2C, '%m-%d')

y$X3O<- as.Date(y$X3O, '%m-%d')

y$X3C<- as.Date(y$X3C, '%m-%d')

y[is.na(y[, c(5:10)])]<-"1999-12-12"
y$x1O[is.na(y$x1O)]<-"1999-12-12"
y$X1C[is.na(y$X1C)]<-"1999-12-12"
y$X2O[is.na(y$X2O)]<-"1999-12-12"
y$X2C[is.na(y$X2C)]<-"1999-12-12"
y$X3O[is.na(y$X3O)]<-"1999-12-12"
y$X3C[is.na(y$X3C)]<-"1999-12-12"

y[,"correct" ]<- is.between(y$arrive , y$x1O , y$X1C) | is.between(y$arrive ,  y$X2O, y$X2C)  |is.between(y$arrive ,  y$X3O, y$X3C) | is.between(y$departure, y$x1O , y$X1C) | is.between(y$departure ,  y$X2O, y$X2C)  |is.between(y$departure ,  y$X3O, y$X3C)
```